# Combinatorial Sampling

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Assume there is a sack with **N** (**N**>**2**) balls, **K** (**0**<**K**<**N**) of which are white, the others are black. By some method **n** (**0**<**n**<**N**) balls were drawn, among which **k** (**0**<=**k**<=**n**) are white. The null hypothesis is that the method draws randomly. Find the p-value based on given **N**, **K**, **n**, **k**.

In other words, if for the observed situation **k**/**n** is somewhat differs from **K**/**N**, what is the probability that the drawing method is still random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is relatively small compared with $N$ (say less than 10%)
you can use a binomial test with $k$ successes out of $N$ trials
(or a normal approximation to it). Otherwise, it might be feasible
to use the hypergeometric variance instead of the binomial variance
in a normal approximation.

If you need to make an exact hypergeometric test, then perhaps
[another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92279/) on this site will be useful.

If you can give more specifics about your data and your objectives,
perhaps I (or someone else here) can give you better advice.

Comment: Thank you! Hypergeometric test is exactly what I was looking for. Previously I was using binomial test, but it was too inaccurate, since n/N is ~25% in my case

Comment: @Roman: Good to use hypergeometric then. Name may be the most complicated thing about it.